# Outlook 2007 alternative to margin-bottom

Tags: email, html-email, email-templates

I'm getting very frustrated here.

What alternative to margin-bottom do you use in e-mail templates?

Answer (score 1):

I have resorted to using tables to format email templates for outlook.  You can create a row and column 5-10px wide on both sides or top and bottom of one big cell, and then i just put my standard code in the main table cell.  It's kind of clunky, but it solves the problem.

Comment: I'm making a template, where I need to seperate all content with `Table`s. That means that the margin should be between `Table`s.